# Can a Salesforce Essentials Org be upgraded to a professional or enterprise Org?

Tags: community, licenses

I have a client considering going with Salesforce Essentials to test Salesforce out. However, they have a need for several features in Enterprise edition that they want to implement if the initial test period goes well.

A long time ago I was told that Salesforce Essentials cannot be upgraded to Professional or Enterprise and that you have to start a new org entirely. This would incur a lot of cost to transition between orgs. Does anyone know if this is still the case?

Comment: You'd have to ask Technical Support.

Answer (score 2):

I spoke with Salesforce and they indicated that you can upgrade essentials to professional, enterprise, etc.